# How is checking for char value in a nullable long valid in C#

Tags: c#

I was going through a piece of C# code which is like this:

```
if (((long)ShopperId != 0) && ((long)ShopperId != null) && ((long)ShopperId != '0'))
```

I understand the first two checks, but what about the third?
How is this even a valid C# statement.

This however has been in production for some time now without any errors.

Comment: The '0' character represents also a short value. I don't know if it's correct, but it seems courios.

Comment: Also, you will want to ass that null check before the 0 check.

Comment: Actually the more curious part is `((long)ShopperId != null)`. That makes absolutely no sense. What is the type of `ShopperId` ?

Answer (score 5):

`Char`s are implicitly convertible to any of:

> `ushort`, `int`, `uint`, `long`, `ulong`, `float`, `double`, or `decimal`

as per the C# language specification ([version 5](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029), section 6.1.2).

You'll note that [`Char`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is defined as:

> Represents a character as a UTF-16 code unit.

So it can easily fit into any numeric type that has at least 16-bits of precision.

---

So that answers the "why it compiles" part of the question. To the implicit "does this code make sense?" question, the answer is "probably not". You wouldn't normally be using `(long)'0'` as a third "sentinel" value to indicate the same "thing" as `0` or `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Iam not 100% sure but i think that the '0' is interpreted as char and any char has a ascii code. So you will check is shopperId same like ascii code of 0.

Ascii of '0' is 48 in decimal. So you are checking `((long)ShopperId != 48)`

Answer (score 0):

All characters translate into an integer (or short, because it is a byte (8 bits)) value, so, according to the standard ASCII table, '0' would translate into 48 (or 0x30 in hexadecimal), thus that expression is the same as ((long)ShopperId != 48)).

Answer (score 0):

The char type represents a character. A value type, char is similar to an integer (or ushort). It is two bytes in width. You can certainly cast it to integer or long.

Consider this as a demonstration,

```
char c = 'a';
int i;
long l;    

i = c;
l = c;

Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}",c, i, l);
```